# Android WorkManager kicking off too many jobs simultaneously

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm implementing parallel background upload/download functionality in my app using workmanager. Everything works great except WorkManager runs too many jobs simultaneously and the phone becomes unresponsive until things spool down. I'd like to enqueue say 10 tasks and have WM execute say 2 in parallel until all 10 are done. WorkManager seems to execute 5-10 in parallel. I can not figure out how to do this. I've tried my own Configuration with just a single threaded executor and it doesn't make any difference. How can I constrain the number of jobs executed at once? I'm using 1.0.0-rc01.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom `Configuration` to define the number of `Worker`s that you want to execute simultaneously. Something like this in your `Application.onCreate()`. For more information read about how to initialize `WorkManager` with a custom configuration.

```
val config = Configuration.Builder()
  .setExecutor(yourExecutor)
  .build()

WorkManager.initialize(context, config)
```

Comment: I tried that with a single threaded executor, makes no difference

Comment: Make sure you initialized WorkManager correctly. You need to _disable_ the default initializer otherwise the second call to `initialize` will have no effect. You will only see a warning that its already been initialized.

Comment: Still having this problem with 2.1.0-beta02. I'm using ListenableWorker if that makes a difference. It doesn't matter if I override the configuration, it still kicks off way more jobs than Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2) should allow. 10-20 vs 2. The default initializer is disabled.

Comment: I have the same experience as @2fours. I tried 
.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))
but it does not limit it to 5 Workers running at a given time, it definitely exceeds this in my  testing of this.

Comment: I opened an issue on their bug tracker
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155370056

Answer (score 1):

i test this example code and work for me without any bug, 10 parallel execution node(`.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))`) for download file without any lag and freeze UI thread:
i use `implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-beta02'`.
on your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<application        
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:authorities="de.stocard.stocard.workmanager-init"
        android:enabled="false"
        tools:replace="android:authorities"/>

</application>
```

in `App.java`:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder()
            .setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
            .build();
WorkManager.initialize(getApplicationContext(), configuration);
```

in `MainActivity.java`:

```
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkA = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkA.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkB = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkB.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkC = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkC.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkD = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkD.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkE = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkE.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkF = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkF.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkG = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkG.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkH = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkH.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkI = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkI.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkJ = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkJ.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkK = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWork.class)
        .build();
OneTimeWorkRequest MyWorkL = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkL.class)
        .build();
List<OneTimeWorkRequest> allWorker = new ArrayList<>();
allWorker.add(MyWorkA);
allWorker.add(MyWorkB);
allWorker.add(MyWorkC);
allWorker.add(MyWorkD);
allWorker.add(MyWorkE);
allWorker.add(MyWorkF);
allWorker.add(MyWorkG);
allWorker.add(MyWorkH);
allWorker.add(MyWorkI);
allWorker.add(MyWorkJ);
WorkManager.getInstance()
        .enqueue(allWorker);
```

and for `MyWorkA.java` to `MyWorkJ.java` use this code(dummy download file):

```
public class MyWorkA extends Worker {

    private static final String TAB = MyWorkA.class.getSimpleName();

    public MyWorkA(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        Log.e(TAB,"My WorkA");

        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/20MB.zip");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            }

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_nameA.zip");

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                total += count;
                if (fileLength > 0)
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("test", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ListenableWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker) then custom [Configuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration) with [setExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Configuration.Builder#setExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)) will not help. Reason being this [executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor) is only meant for running the [Worker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker) and not ListenableWorker.  So in this particular case, you can have your own fixed thread pool, which you can use while [starting the background process](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#startWork()). One of the way to achieve this with fixed thread pool in [ExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService) -

```
public class MyExecutorService {
    private static ExecutorService executorService = null;

    public static ExecutorService getExecutorService() {
        if (executorService == null) {
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        }
        return executorService;
    }
}


public class MyListenableWorker extends ListenableWorker {

    public MyListenableWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(appContext, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        MyExecutorService.getExecutorService().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doBackgroundWork();
            }
        });

        return future; // see note below
    }
}
```

**Note**: If you are using your custom ListenableWorker, you need to maintain status of ListenableFuture like mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker).

Comment: What does this look like when you are dealing with an `RxWorker` and not a `ListenableWorker`.  The RxWorker i have created currently implements all of the logic in 
`override fun createWork(): Single<Result> { }`
so how would this change in the case of an `RxWorker`?

Comment: In that case you can provide the executor with fixed thread pool in the configuration.  But I see it doesn't work for you.  So as an alternative, you can override the getBackgroundScheduler() method in your RxWorker class and return the Scheduler with fixed thread pool.  Like this - 
    protected Scheduler getBackgroundScheduler() {
        return Schedulers.from(MyExecutorService.getExecutorService());
    }